# Import from SQL Server, data types not converted properly

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, avro

Import from SQL Server, data types not converted properly
Stack : Installed HDP-2.3.2.0-2950 using Ambari 2.1

Objective :

- Import tables from SQL Server onto HDFS in Avro format
- Create EXTERNAL Hive Avro(SerDe) tables which have all the data
- Create EXTERNAL Hive ORC tables and insert into ORC select * from
  Avro tables
- Drop the Avro tables and perform testing on the ORC tables

One of the tables :

```
ECU_DTC_ID          int
DTC_CDE             nchar(20)
ECU_NAME            nvarchar(15)
ECU_FAMILY_NAME     nvarchar(15)
DTC_DESC            nvarchar(MAX)
INSERTED_BY         nvarchar(64)
INSERTION_DATE      datetime
DTC_CDE_DECIMAL     int
```

When I execute the normal sqoop import, the datetime is converted to long, nchar and nvarchar to String. The resultant avsc file is as shown, when I create a Hive Avro table, it doesn't include the generated avro files, thus leaving behind an empty table :

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "DimECUDTCCode",
  "doc" : "Sqoop import of DimECUDTCCode",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "ECU_DTC_ID",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "ECU_DTC_ID",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  }, {
    "name" : "DTC_CDE",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "DTC_CDE",
    "sqlType" : "-15"
  }, {
    "name" : "ECU_NAME",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "ECU_NAME",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "ECU_FAMILY_NAME",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "ECU_FAMILY_NAME",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "DTC_DESC",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "DTC_DESC",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "INSERTED_BY",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "INSERTED_BY",
    "sqlType" : "-9"
  }, {
    "name" : "INSERTION_DATE",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "INSERTION_DATE",
    "sqlType" : "93"
  }, {
    "name" : "DTC_CDE_DECIMAL",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "DTC_CDE_DECIMAL",
    "sqlType" : "4"
  } ],
  "tableName" : "DimECUDTCCode"
```

I decided to include **--map-column-java** :

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://somedbserver;database=somedb' --username someusername--password somepassword --as-avrodatafile --num-mappers 8 --table DimECUDTCCode --map-column-java DTC_CDE=string,ECU_NAME=string,ECU_FAMILY_NAME=string,DTC_DESC=string,INSERTED_BY=string,INSERTION_DATE=timestamp --warehouse-dir /dataload/tohdfs/reio/odpdw/may2016 --verbose
```

but I get the following error :

```
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No ResultSet method for Java type string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No ResultSet method for Java type string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column ECU_FAMILY_NAME to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No ResultSet method for Java type string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_DESC to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No ResultSet method for Java type string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTED_BY to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No ResultSet method for Java type string
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column INSERTION_DATE to timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No ResultSet method for Java type timestamp
16/05/12 09:43:12 INFO orm.ClassWriter: Overriding type of column DTC_CDE to string
16/05/12 09:43:12 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: No ResultSet method for Java type string
[sqoop@l1038lab root]$
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: you can try `--map-column-hive` and directly map SQL Server columns to the hive columns.

Comment: But why hive, I wish to use java which is not succeeding

Comment: Yes, you should try to find issue using `--map-column-java`. I was just giving an alternative if you got stuck because I tried `--map-column-hive` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `STRING` and `String` and `string` are treated differently by SQOOP. Right way is `String`.